# Why is the size of a character sizeof('a') different in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, types, char, sizeof

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("sizeof(char) = %zu\n", sizeof(char));
    printf("sizeof('a')  = %zu\n", sizeof('a'));
}
```

*See https://godbolt.org/z/1eThqvMhx*

When running this code in C, it prints

```
sizeof(char) = 1
sizeof('a')  = 4
```

When running this code in C++, it prints

```
sizeof(char) = 1
sizeof('a')  = 1
```

Why does the output differ between languages?
What is the size of a character in C and C++? As far as I know, the size of `char` is 1 byte in both C and C++.

Answer (score 406, accepted):

In C, the type of a character *constant* like `'a'` is actually an `int`, with size of 4 (or some other implementation-dependent value). In C++, the type is `char`, with size of 1. This is one of many small differences between the two languages.

Comment: Okay, Can you please specify the standard reference ? :)

Comment: This is pretty much a generic answer given the above code, :P

Comment: In the C++ Standard it's section 2.13.2/1, in C 6.4.4.4, at least in the doc I've got.

Comment: +1 (Except that, while the "size of 4" obviously applies to nthrgeek's platform, it doesn't necessarily apply to all platforms.)

Comment: @nthrgeek: I'm too lazy to quote both standards, but the C++ standard has an appendix dedicated to incompatibilities with C. Under Appendix C.1.1, it mentions that "Type of character literal is changed from `int` to `char`, which explains the behavior. :)

Comment: It makes sense that C and C++ would have this difference.  C++ is much more strongly typed than C.

Comment: @nthrgeek: §6.4.4.4, paragraph 10: "An integer character constant has type int. The value of an integer character constant containing a single character that maps to a single-byte execution character is the numerical value of the representation of the mapped character interpreted as an integer."

Comment: @Omnifarious: It's especially needed in C++ for overloading: `void foo(int); void foo(char);` That's not an issue in C.

Comment: @nthrgeek: You should not be asking for a standard reference unless you are having an argument about a specific point and you want to understand why the other person has a different opinion. If everybody agrees just accept it. You (as a developer) should be quite intelligent enough to quickly find common answer like this all by yourself.

Comment: What about `sizeof` and types of unicode characters?

`sizeof('Ç') == 4` and `std::is_same<int, decltype('Ç')>() == true`

is what I get from g++ while in UTF-8 (which is what I use) Ç should take only two bytes.

Comment: The answer can be improved. sizeof(char)==1 in C++, and 1 means 1 byte in C++. 1 byte does not necessary mean 8 bits though. I know that the answer is already old, but it would be great to add this:
**[intro.memory]** _The fundamental storage unit in the C++ memory model is the byte. A byte is at least large enough to contain
any member of the basic execution character set (2.3) and the eight-bit code units of the Unicode UTF-8
encoding form and is composed of a contiguous sequence of bits, the number of which is implementation defined_

Answer (score 33):

As Paul stated, it's because `'a'` is an `int` in C but a `char` in C++.

I cover that specific difference between C and C++ in something I wrote a few years ago, at: [http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm](http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm#C99-char-literal)

Comment: Just curious, but are you working on updating that (very detailed) doc to include the new changes in C++11 and C11?

Comment: Not at the moment. My interest in C and C++ has waned a lot in the last five years or so.

Answer (score 23):

In C the type of character literals are **int** and **char** in C++. This is in C++ required to **support function overloading**. See this example:

```
void foo(char c)
{
    puts("char");
}
void foo(int i)
{
    puts("int");
}
int main()
{
    foo('i');
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
char
```

Comment: Interesting detail not mentioned in the other answers. Thanks.

Comment: best explanation, should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

**In C language**, character literal is not a `char` type. C considers character literal as integer. So, there is no difference between `sizeof('a')` and `sizeof(1)`.

So, the sizeof character literal is equal to sizeof integer in C.

**In C++ language**, character literal is type of `char`. The [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) say's:

> 1) **narrow character literal or ordinary character literal, e.g. `'a'` or
>   `'\n'` or `'\13'`. Such literal has type `char`** and the value equal to the
>   representation of c-char in the execution character set. If c-char is
>   not representable as a single byte in the execution character set, the
>   literal has type int and implementation-defined value.

So, in C++ character literal is a type of `char`. so, size of character literal in C++ is one byte.

Alos, In your programs, you have used wrong format specifier for `sizeof` operator.

**C11 §7.21.6.1 (P9) :**

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
>   undefined.275) **If any argument is not the correct type for the
>   corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.**

So, you should use `%zu` format specifier instead of `%d`, otherwise it is undefined behaviour in C.

Comment: `%zu` is not supported on many platforms, but better portability, use `(int)sizeof(char)` and format `%d`

Comment: The value of character literals is not necessarily the corresponding ASCII code. It depends on the source and execution character sets and whether the `char` type is signed or unsigned by default.