# Operator sizeof() in C

Tags: c, types, sizeof

Consider the program

```
main()  
{  
 printf("%d %d %d",sizeof('3'),sizeof("3"),sizeof(3));  
}
```

output from a **gcc compiler** is:

```
4 2 4
```

Why is it so?

Comment: check for sizeof(int) and sizeof(char) and sizeof(char *)

Comment: `sizeof` is not a function but an operator.

Comment: @benjamin button: different order would match OP's question :)

Comment: values of those are more important over here than the order

Comment: the values differ from machine to machine and compiler to compiler.so i need the answer from Mohit

Comment: @tusbar: hence "fyi", and see @IVlad's answer. @benjamin button: true, it would just be more obvious to match each type to what OP asked for, just a cosmetic detail.

Comment: Your example values seem not to be correct. I cannot imagine a compile which makes a char with size of 4 and a pointer with 2 bytes in size..

Comment: @benjamin, that's wrong. `'3'` has type `int` in C.

Comment: @codymanix: `"3"` is not a pointer, it's an array of 2 elements each of size 1, and thus has size 2.

Comment: @codymanix: OP's values are the values the compiler yields, just compile it yourself.

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you are running on a 32-bit system:

sizeof a character literal '3' is 4 because character literals are ints in C language (but not C++).

sizeof "3" is 2 because it is an array literal with length 2 (numeral 3 plus NULL terminator).

sizeof literal 3 is 4 because it is an int.

Comment: The answers to this question help explain some more - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252033/in-c-why-is-sizeofchar-1-when-a-is-an-int

Comment: In C, char literals are of type int.  Not so with C++.

Answer (score 12):

A few points to keep in mind:

1. `sizeof` isn't a function, it's an operator. It returns the size of a type in units of `sizeof char`. In other words `sizeof char` is always 1.
2. '3' is an `int`
3. "3" is a `char[2]`, the character 3 then the null terminator.
4. 3 is an `int`

With these the differences are easily explained:

1. an `int` requires 4 `char`s of space to hold it
2. `char[2]` naturally only requires 2 `char`s

Comment: +1 for mentioning `sizeof` is an operator. Pet peeve of mine: The braces in `sizeof (char)` belong to the type (where they are needed). They can (and should) be omitted in `sizeof '3'`.

Answer (score 3):

To quote K & R,

> Each compiler is free to choose
>   appropriate sizes for its own 
>   hardware, subject only to the the
>   restriction that shorts and ints are
>   at least 16 bits, longs are at least
>   32 bits, and short is no longer than
>   int, which is no longer than long.

Answer (score 0):

sizeof() Output depends on compiler you are using