# Why sizeof(array) is multiplied?

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

This make no sense for me:

```
    int start_tab[2];
    printf("size of an array: %d\n", sizeof(start_tab));
    8
```

Why 8?
How make it to be size of 2?

Comment: sorry, I used to programming in higher languages and this seems to be obvious, but now I am too mad for just reading.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator sizeof() in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334233/operator-sizeof-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please be noted, `sizeof` is an operator, not a function. `sizeof` returns the size of the supplied datatype.

> Why 8?

`start_tab` being of type `int [2]`, returns `2 * sizeof (int)`<sup>#</sup> or `8`.

> How make it to be size of 2?

If you want to get the *count* of element in the array, simply divide the total size by the size of a single element, like

```
sizeof(start_tab) / sizeof(start_tab[0])
```

---

<sup># In your platform, `sizeof(int)` == 4.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You need to divide by the size of the type like this

```
sizeof(start_tab) / sizeof(int)
```

`sizeof` gives the size in bytes, since each `int` is `4` bytes then two of them are obviously eight, so you can divide by the size of an `int` and get the value you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You have to do `sizeof(start_tab)/sizeof(start_tab[0])` to get the number of elements in an array

Answer (score 2):

Because an int is `4` bytes... so multiply by `2` makes `8` So if you want the element size divide by `sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 2):

Because `int` is on your platform 32 bit which is `4` bytes. You have `2` `int`s multiplied with 32 bit equals 64 bit which is `8` byte. `sizeof` will return the size of a datatype in bytes.

Answer (score 2):

From the C Standard (6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators)

> 2 **The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand**,
>   which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type.

Array

```
int start_tab[2];
```

occupies `2 * sizeof( int )` **bytes** because it has two elements and each element has type `int`. So if `sizeof( int )` is equal to `4` then the array occupies `8` **bytes**.

So you have a formula

```
sizeof( start_tab ) = 2 * sizeof( int )
```

Or in general case if an array has N elements of type T like for example

```
T array[N];
```

then

```
sizeof( array ) = N * sizeof( T )
```

Or as each element of the array has type T including the first element of the array then you can also write

```
sizeof( array ) = N * sizeof( array[0] )
```

Using this formula you can calculate N like

```
N = sizeof( array ) / sizeof( array[0] )
```

or

```
N = sizeof( array ) / sizeof( *array )
```

because `*array` yields the first element of the array.