# The program returns an error when I try to generate a random character. warning C4242:

Tags: c

warning C4242: 'function': conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(0));
    int lucky = (rand() % 26) + 65;

    printf("> %d", lucky);

    return 0;
}
```

I am expecting the program to output a random letter between uppercase A to uppercase Z.

The srand function seems to be working with other programs but not here. Not sure why.

Comment: Why are you expecting that? ` %d"` outputs a number, not a character.

Comment: `time` returns a `time_t`. `time_t` is signed and isn't necessarily the same size as an `int`. `srand` expects an unsigned `int`, so you've got two strikes against you.  The compiler is warning you that some of the time could be lost.

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: `printf("> %d", lucky);` prints an integer instead of a character.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4736764/918959

Comment: @NeilButterworth That's just me trying different thing to see if it works. I will correct it now.

Comment: By editing your question after receiving answers, you have made the existing answer almost completely irrelevant.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank you guys for that, I will note that down.

Answer (score 2):

You are instructing `printf` to output the value as an integer.  To output a character, you need to use `%c` format specifier.

It is also preferable to use character constants instead of hard-coded numbers, for clarity.  And, while not strictly necessary for `printf`, your `lucky` type should probably be `char` since you intend it to represent a character:

```
char lucky = (rand() % 26) + 'A';
printf("> %c", lucky);
```

Comment: Might be worth an edit to hammer home the point that the problem the asker is facing has absolutely nothing to do with the compiler warning.

Comment: This is just me trying different things, sorry new to this.

Comment: But what bothers me is the error:"error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated" which is indicating that my "srand(time(0))" is wrong? I believe it doesn't have anything wrong with the rest of the code?

Comment: Regarding "warning treated as error", yes that's an issue for you.  It will cause compilation to fail if any warnings are encountered.  Generally, it's a good idea to keep this enabled because warnings are there for a reason.  Just fix the warning, which you can do after reviewing the question that was referenced as already providing an answer.

Comment: @paddy Cheers, thanks for that.