# Why in My Code, Type Casting is not Working in C?

Tags: c, casting, type-conversion

it is printing the value to be 55 instead of 7.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a = '7';
    printf("%d", (int)a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The value of '7' is 55, the value of 7 is 7, consult your ASCII table.

Comment: I can **completely** understand having this same question when I was learning C.

Comment: "Why in My Code, Type Casting is not Working in C?" - Type casting is working perfectly fine. It is giving the result the standard is requiring. It is just not the result you *expect*.

Comment: Hint; messages like "ps. don't downvote me" will *usually* have the direct opposite effect of what you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing a char with printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736732/printing-a-char-with-printf)

Comment: @JesperJuhl - wasn't that said by Barbra Streisand? :-)

Answer (score 4):

ASCII characters are represented by numbers. The *numeric* value of the character `'7'` is `55`. As the characters `'0'` to `'9'` are laid out sequentially in ASCII, you can subtract `'0'` from `'7'` to get the number `7`.

Comment: I started with _"Once upon a time, before [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) ..."_ - but, nah. +1

Comment: And thus was a magnificent bit of writing lost to the world. (Not being even slightly sarcastic, by the way.)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char a = '7';
printf("%c",a);
return 0;
}
```

for character, you need to use `%c`. Your are getting `55` because in your code you tried to print numerical value of `7`.