# sizeof('a') vs size('aa')

Tags: c++, char, int, byte, sizeof

I have tried doing research through google and SO but I can only find [results](http://c-faq.com/charstring/sd5.html) for `sizeof('a')` which is type `int` and thus should give me 4 bytes, but when I run this I get 1 byte (I think it might be because the link I have is a reference for C and not C++).  HOWEVER what is interesting here is that when I type `sizeof('aa')` I get 4 bytes.  And anymore characters after `aa` (for example `aaa` or `aaaa`) still gives me 4 bytes.  Why is there a sudden increase in 3 bytes that remains constant with the addition of more chars?  Also why does the sizeof(int) here give me 1 byte?

Thanks!

Comment: Character literals have type `char` in C++. Multicharacter literals have type `int`.

Comment: This is one place where C and C++ are different. In C `'a'` is an `int`, in C++ it is not for reasons of overloading functions.

Comment: [Size of character ('a') in C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172943/size-of-character-a-in-c-c?lq=1) [In C, why is sizeof(char) 1, when 'a' is an int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252033/in-c-why-is-sizeofchar-1-when-a-is-an-int?rq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `sizeof('a')` which is type `int`

Neither one of `'a'` or `sizeof('a')` is an `int`. In C++, one-character literals are of type `char`, and the type of a `sizeof()` expression is `size_t`.

Furthermore:

> type `int` [...] should give me 4 bytes

No, `int` need not necessarily be exactly 4 bytes long.

Comment: Since we are on the topic of sizeof(), I have one more question. I noticed that you said int need not necessarily be exactly 4 bytes long so I decided to play around with my code and test what range is for a type int variable. Here I made a declaration:

`int x = 18446744073709551615`, 

which is just 2^64 or in other words int is 16 byte size.  Then why is sizeof(int) giving me 4 bytes?

Also according to http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/24-integers/,  a size of 4 bytes should give me a range between -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

Thanks again!

Comment: Maybe you should explain about `aa`?

Comment: @JustinLiang "2^64 or in other words int is 16 byte size." - ***What?*** 64 bits are 8 bytes, assuming a 8-bit byte. Or are bytes 4-bit long on your platform? Also, what do `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` evaluate to?

Comment: Oops sorry I meant 64 bits are 8 bytes.  INT_MAX and INT_MIN evaluate to -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647 respectively.

Comment: @JustinLiang Then I don't see what's that with the 8 bytes. With these values of `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` and `sizeof(int)` yielding 4, `int` is ***100% positively certainly 4 bytes long.***

Comment: Hmmm, then how come `int x = 18446744073709551615` works?  Why is it that `int` can store numbers bigger than 2,147,483,647?  Shouldn't we expect overflow?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now.  I used `cout` after declaring `int x = 18446744073709551615` and it printed 1 onto the screen.  The reason why I thought it worked was because initially I did not use `cout` and the program compiled fine.  HOWEVER when I changed my declaration to `int x = 18446744073709551616` (here I added 1 to 18446744073709551615) I would get the compilation error `integer constant too large`.  But now I think it makes sense to get an error because the largest size of any variable type is 8 bytes, so we should expect an error when trying to store anything bigger than 8 bytes.