# Storing a character constant in a character variable

Tags: c

```
char ch = 'a';
```

Here ch is a character variable, so it's size is one byte. 'a' is a character constant,so it's ASCII value will be stored which is 2 byte.But how could it possible to store a 2 byte value in an 1 byte variable ?

Comment: How is the ASCII value of 'a' two bytes long? ASCII is a 7-bit character encoding standard.

Comment: Do not understand. ASCII is a set of 128 characters, so 7 bits should be sufficient to represent all ASCII chars.

Comment: But the size of a character constant is 2 byte or 4 byte ...so how could it possible to store it in 1 byte variable ?

Comment: Maybe Joel will be able to help you: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: I'm wondering where you got that misinformation from? `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1.

Comment: -1 for bogus assumption with no explanation of where you got it from.

Comment: @AndiDog  But sizeof('a') is 2/4 byte...It may b bogus but i didn't get it..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Size of character ('a') in C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172943/size-of-character-a-in-c-c)

Comment: @Parixit: See Jens Gustedt's link, taking `sizeof` of a character literal will return an `int`, not a `char`. But that's another topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A character literal, such as `'a'`, will be treated as an integer literal, such as `97` or `0x61`.  C compilers tend to want every integer to be stored in an `int` unless told otherwise, so `sizeof('a')` will probably be `sizeof(int)`.

You should notice, though, that the value of `'a'` is less than 127 so it can be stored in a char (which has a maximum value of either 127 or 255 depending on if it is signed or unsigned on your compiler).  This is the same as being able to:

```
unsigned long long x = 0;
unsigned int y = x;
```

`y` is assigned from a `x` whose type is bigger than `y`'s type, but `x`'s value is well within those which `y` can represent, so no data is lost when the top bits (all 0s) are chopped off.

Answer (score 2):

Along with other people's responces more somewhat related information can be found at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172943/size-of-character-a-in-c-c).

Answer (score 0):

You've asked a good question. I suggest that you do two things to satisfy yourself that there is enough room to store a character:

1) Look at the documentation for getchar(), and you will see it returns an int, so there is enough room to store a character's value. It is good to understand the underpinnings of the declaration, but if you declare `char cTestChar = 'c';` there is enough room to store the value.

2) Generate an assembly listing when you compile. Visual C/C++ supports this as well as gcc. gcc uses the -Wa option to generate assembly output. The map will show the allocation of a character type.

Answer (score -2):

Well a character constant is only one byte...

Comment: The type of a character literal is actually `int` in C.

Comment: `sizeof('c')` returns 1 with VS2010 and gcc 4.3

Comment: We're talking about C, not C++. In C++, `sizeof('c')` is 1.