# sizeof('z') result unexpected

Tags: c, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Size of character ('a') in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172943/size-of-character-a-in-c-c)

Why does this program output 4 and not 1?

```
void main()
{
   printf("%d",int(sizeof('z')));
}
```

'z' is a character and `sizeof('z')` must print 1?

Comment: A hint: `char ch = 'z'; printf("%d", sizeof ch);`

Comment: @tjm I think it is -- nice find. (And vote cast).

Comment: What does it say about the uselessness of the SO search facility that I know I have a high-rep answer to this, but still cannot find it!

Comment: In fact the dupe answer is by me! But I couldn't find it.

Comment: @Neil, I don't know about the SO search, but it does come up as the first result if you google "c sizeof character"

Comment: @tjm well for me the wikipedia article comes up first. But still - anonymous fame at last!

Comment: -1 `void main` **RAAAAAAAAARRRRRRRRRGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHH**

Answer (score 8):

`'z'` is a character literal and in C a character literal is of type `int`. So `sizeof('z')` equals `sizeof(int)` on your implementation.

Answer (score 8):

[Sizeof char](http://c-faq.com/charstring/sizeofchar.html).

> Perhaps surprisingly, **character
>   constants in C are of type int**, so
>   `sizeof('a')` is `sizeof(int)`