# difference between sizeof('a') and sizeof("a")

Tags: c, sizeof

My question is about the `sizeof` operator in C.

`sizeof('a');` equals *4*, as it will take `'a'` as an integer: 97.

`sizeof("a");` equals *2*: why? Also `(int)("a")` will give some garbage value. Why?

Comment: char vs. integer vs. string :)  "sizeof('a')" happens to be promoted to "sizeof (int)".  And I'm guessing you already know why "a\0" is "2" :)  And I guess you'll understand why (int)(SOME-STRING-ADDRESS) will appear as "garbage" :)

Comment: I would have thought sizeof('a') == 1 [same as sizeof(char) == 1] and sizeof("a") == 4 [same as sizeof(char *) == 4]. Interesting.

Comment: @Johnny Mopp: [Why are C character literals ints instead of chars?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/why-are-c-character-literals-ints-instead-of-chars)

Comment: possible duplicate of [sizeof('z') result unexpected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163776/sizeofz-result-unexpected)

Comment: @Jens Gustedt - not a duplicate.  The OP is asking two other (directly related, entirely relevant!) things besides "sizeof (character literal)".  IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4, I know, I meant this more as an incentive to do some research before asking here.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`'a'` is a *character constant* - of type `int` in standard C - and represents a single *character*. `"a"` is a different sort of thing: it's a *string literal*, and  is actually made up of *two* characters: `a` and a terminating null character.

A string literal is an array of `char`, with enough space to hold each character in the string and the terminating null character. Because `sizeof(char)` is `1`, and because a string literal is an array, `sizeof("stringliteral")` will return the number of character elements in the string literal *including* the terminating null character.

That `'a'` is an `int` instead of a `char` is a quirk of standard C, and explains why `sizeof('a') == 4`: it's because `sizeof('a') == sizeof(int)`. This is **not** the case in C++, where `sizeof('a') == sizeof(char)`.

Comment: I know the question is tagged C, but I think it's valuable to point out that in C++ `sizeof('a') == 1` (one of the breaking changes between C and C++).

Answer (score 4):

because 'a' is a character, while "a" is a string consisting of the 'a' character followed by a null.