# Concatenate two strings error

Tags: c, concatenation

I am getting a segmentation fault when i try to concatenate two strings as shown in the code below:

**EDITED**

```
//global variables
char *result="hi";
char *temp;

size_t write_data(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmeb, void *stream)
{
  temp=(char *)ptr;

  while(*result)++result;

  while(*result++ = *temp++);

  return fwrite(ptr,size,nmeb,stream);
}
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Um... where's `result` initialized?

Comment: Initializing result to "hi" or "\0" give me segmentation fault.

Comment: Refer K&R book on how to write strcat(). That should give you a very good idea on what's going wrong in your program.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to add some sort of string in front of `ptr` and then `fwrite` that?

Comment: this is part of curl code. write_data() is a callback function that will be called every time a data chunk is obtained from a web server. what i am trying to do is concatenate each chunk of data together and will finally will send the full data back to the client.

Answer (score 2):

You are storing values into the address pointed to by `result` without having initialized `result` to point to ENOUGH memory that you can use to store the result. By initializing result to "Hi" you have allocated three bytes for it. This is not enough to hold the additional data that you are attempting to append at the end.

Comment: I have changed the code to make result initialize to some value. Still, i get segfault

Comment: thanks for the explanation. but, i do not know how much memory result will occupy. So, what should i do in this case? just allocate arbitrary large memory for it ? that is not a good practice.

Comment: The amount of memory you need is strlen(result) + strlen(ptr) + sizeof('\0') so that is how much you should allocate.

Comment: @JoelSpolsky: sizeof('\0') is equivalent to sizeof(int) in C. In C++, however, sizeof('\0') is equivalent to sizeof(char). See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172943/size-of-character-a-in-c-c).

Answer (score 1):

```
while(*result)++result;   // 1

while(*result++ = *temp++);  // 2
```

By the end of line 1, result reaches its end, and at line 2, you are passing `result` end and dereferencing it.

```
char *result="hi";
```

`result` is pointing to the string literal `hi` with null terminated. Locations after the null termination aren't valid accessible locations for `result` to access. But you are trying to access them at line 2.

Comment: Not sure why it was given -1?

Comment: @downvoter - `result` is a pointer and not an array. So, I think OP is just pointing to a string literal.

Comment: Even if he wasn't pointing past the bounds in the new example, you still can't write to read-only memory.

Comment: @AusCBloke - Yes. OP should have got a warning that it is `const char*` and not `char*`.