# Single, double quotes and sizeof('a') in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I was looking at the question [Single quotes vs. double quotes in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c). I couldn't completely understand the explanation given so I wrote a program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char ch = 'a';
  printf("sizeof(ch) :%d\n", sizeof(ch));
  printf("sizeof(\'a\') :%d\n", sizeof('a'));
  printf("sizeof(\"a\") :%d\n", sizeof("a"));
  printf("sizeof(char) :%d\n", sizeof(char));
  printf("sizeof(int) :%d\n", sizeof(int));
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled them using both gcc and g++ and these are my outputs:

#### gcc:

```
sizeof(ch)   : 1  
sizeof('a')  : 4  
sizeof("a")  : 2  
sizeof(char) : 1  
sizeof(int)  : 4
```

#### g++:

```
sizeof(ch)   : 1  
sizeof('a')  : 1  
sizeof("a")  : 2  
sizeof(char) : 1  
sizeof(int)  : 4
```

The g++ output makes sense to me and I don't have any doubt regarding that. In gcc, what is the need to have `sizeof('a')` to be different from `sizeof(char)`? Is there some actual reason behind it or is it just historical?

Also in C if `char` and `'a'` have different size, does that mean that when we write 
`char ch = 'a';`, we are doing implicit type-conversion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Size of character ('a') in C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172943/size-of-character-a-in-c-c)

Comment: I'm actually surprised by `sizeof("a")  : 2` - all these years, and I always assumed that would be the same as `sizeof(char*)` - I might have actually used it if I had known otherwise.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

In C, character constants such as `'a'` have type `int`, in C++ it's `char`.

Regarding the last question, yes,

```
char ch = 'a';
```

causes an implicit conversion of the `int` to `char`.

Comment: +1:  @Pratt:  in 1970s C usage, `int` was the return type for `getc()`.  It uses -1 to indicate EOF which was also a handy convention for many other things frequently done with `char` expressions, like indexing into an array for character-break processing, char string transformation (like `stricmp()`) etc.

Comment: @wallyk: `getc()` still returns `int`, and it still returns `EOF` to indicate that there are no more characters to be read. `EOF` is defined to be a negative `int` value; it's typically `-1`.

Comment: And the reason C++ changed the rules is because you can overload functions.

Comment: Very nice topic,answer and comments. :)

Comment: @KeithThompson the `int` returned by `getc` and friends is a different sort of `int` to the character constants though!  Character constants may be negative, but the `getc` are all non-negative values. What would be negative character values are adjusted modulo `UCHAR_MAX+1`.

Comment: @M.M: I'm not sure what you mean by "a different sort of `int`". Yes, character constants can be negative (but only if plain `char` is signed, and only for values outside the basic execution character set). And of course `getc()` can return `EOF`, which is negative.

Answer (score 1):

because there is no char just intgers linked int a character

like a is 62 i guess

if you try printf("%c",62); you will see a character