# usage of two characters in single quotes in c

Tags: c

```
         #include<stdio.h>

         int main()
         {

           char ch = 'A';

           printf("%d\n",'ag');

           printf("%d\n",'a');

           printf("%d, %d, %d, %d", sizeof(ch), sizeof('a'), sizeof('Ag'), sizeof(3.14f));

          return 0;
         }
```

I used to have many doubts on the output of this question while running on g++ and gcc.

But I have cleared almost all the doubts by referring these links:

1. [Single, double quotes and sizeof('a') in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606807/single-and-double-quotes-in-c-c)
2. [Single quotes vs. double quotes in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683602/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-c)

I still need to understand one thing about the output of this question.

Can someone please explain the output of `printf("%d\n",'ag');` mentioned above in the program. How is it actually stored in the memory?

The output for the program on the Linux/GCC platform is:

```
24935
97
1, 4, 4, 4
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737320/how-to-determine-the-result-of-assigning-multi-character-char-constant-to-a-char/11737414#11737414

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of a single-quoted literal is `int`. So the size is typically large enough for more than one character's worth of bits. The exact way the characters are interpreted is, as far as I know, implementation-dependent.

In your case, you're getting a little-endian ordering:

- The ASCII value for `'a'` is 97 (0x61)
- The ASCII value for `'g'` is 103 (0x67)

Your value is 24935 = 0x6167, so you're getting the `'a'` in the higher byte and the `'g'` in the lower.

Comment: Confirming the implementation-defined part: ISO/IEC 9899, 6.4.4.4:10: *The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g., 'ab'), or containing a character or escape sequence that does not map to a single-byte execution character, is implementation-defined.*

Answer (score 3):

What multiple characters mean in single quotes is implementation defined.

> 6.4.4.4
>
> An integer character constant has type int. The value of an integer
>   character constant containing  a  single  character  that  maps  to  a
>   single-byte  execution  character  is  the numerical value of the
>   representation of the mapped character interpreted as an integer. The 
>   value  of  an  integer  character  constant  **containing  more  than 
>   one  character  (e.g., 'ab'),** or containing a character or escape
>   sequence that does not map to a single-byte execution character, is
>   **implementation-deﬁned**.

For example, in this case `24935` is `0x6167`: the ASCII values for the characters `a` and `g` side by side.