# What does '9' mean in C?

Tags: c, character-literals

When writing '9' instead of 9 as my char c my endresult becomes negative and wrong for some reason. Why is that? What does '9' do?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a, b;
    char c = '9';
    a = 44;
    b = a - c;

    printf("%d \n", b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `'9'` means the ASCII glyph/character that is 9. `9` means the number 9. ASCII characters are integers, so `'9'` is really the integer value 57.

Comment: `9` is an integer, a number, one less than the number of fingers on your hand. `'9'` is a character, ASCII code 57, one less than `':'`.  (Try printfing them both using `%d`.)

Comment: possible duplicates: [usage of two characters in single quotes in c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12212668/995714), [Single quotes vs. double quotes in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3683602/995714). You need to [read a good C book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/995714), stackoverflow isn't a place for asking things like this

Comment: If you want to subtract nine from something, you definitely want to subtract `9`.  Subtracting `'9'` is pretty meaningless, since it's analogous to subtracting `'Q'`, or subtracting `'$'`.

Comment: @SteveSummit that's quite a hand!

Comment: @mnistic I need to ask you to add an `'s'` (not 115) to the word "hand" in that comment...

Answer (score 5):

`'9'` and `9` are both integer constants.

- 9 has integer value of nine
- `'9'` - has integer value of the (usually) ASCII code of symbol `'9'`. It is `57` It is for our convenience when we deal with strings and characters.

```
    char c = '9';
    int a = 44;
    int b = a - c;
```

- `char` is also integer type having size 1 (`sizeof(char)` is by definition `1`) Variable `c` has integer value of 57.
- `c` is being converted to `int` and it is subtracted from `a` (`44-57`). The result is assigned to `b`

ASCII table:
[image]

There are other coding conventions and standards (like EBCDIC), but it is very unlikely nowadays to work on the machine which uses them

Comment: @ikegami it is not correct of course as compiler needs to convert to the correct single character integer. In source code it can be even more than one byte. Examples: `'\n'` `'\141'` `'\x33'`

Comment: @ikegami, it is actually the value of the character `9` in the execution character set.  That's only incidentally connected to the value in the source file, via the fact that source and execution character sets are usually the same.  But they don't *have to be* the same.

Comment: It's not necessarily ASCII. It could be another character set. Like EBCDIC.

Comment: @0___________, I was obviously talking about unescaped characters, just like you were.

Comment: @klutt did you ever program `EBCDIC` computer in C language?

Comment: @John Bollinger, It did seem wrong after I wrote it. Deleted.

Comment: 0___________, I've submitted patches to `perl`, so technically yes I have.

Comment: @ikegami did you use IBM mainframe for that? Or your PC? I am asking if someone here was programming the machine using  EBCDIC in C

Comment: I did not run the code directly -- that's what automated testing is for -- but the code needed to run on such machines, yes. Perl supports EBCDIC machines, and it's written in C.  /// I also deal with data that's encoded using EBCDIC on a daily basis, but the systems I use are ASCII-based.

Comment: @0___________ There are tons of things that I have not done. That does not make them impossible.

Answer (score 1):

`'9'` is a representation of 57, which is the index at which the glyph 9 shows up in the [ASCII table](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Epattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html). As such, `a-c` equals to `44-57`, which yields the negative result.

Answer (score 1):

`char a = '9'` means `a`'s value is the ascii code of the character 9, , which is 57 instead of the value 9.

So `b = a - c` is actually 44 - 57.