# C/C++ sizeof operator: Why does sizeof( 'a' ) return different values?

Tags: c++, c, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Size of character ('a') in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172943/size-of-character-a-in-c-c)

I am a beginner at C, and was confused by this.

`C:` I tried printing the sizeof( 'a' ) in C using the "%zu" modifier, and it prints a value 4.

`C++:` Printing sizeof( 'a' ) in C++ using cout, and printf(using the format above) both printed a value 1.

I believe the correct value should be 1, since 'a' will be taken as a char. Why doesn't it return 4 in C? Are the sizeof operations of both different in both the languages? If so, what's the difference, and why does it return a different value?
I used the gcc compilers in both cases.

Comment: Because C isn't C++.  Not trying to be snide here.  You probably wouldn't be surprised if a char in C was different from a char in Python, but many people think that C is simply a subset of C++.  Not the case at all.  Good answers below, but the bottom line is that C and C++ are 2 different languages.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C, the `'a'` is a character constant, which is treated as an integer, so you get a size of 4, whereas in C++ it's treated as a `char`. This is a duplicate of the question here:

[Size of character ('a') in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172943/size-of-character-a-in-c-c)

Comment: I had tried searching, but it didn't match any questions. Thank you for letting me know of the duplicate.

Comment: -1: There is no definition in C of the size of an Int beyond its size in relation to char and long.

Comment: @mattnz - If you read the linked answer, you can clearly see in the comments (of the first and only answer) that the `sizeof` an `int` is platform dependent. I didn't address this issue because 1. the linked thread addresses it and I expect a mod to close this thread and 2. given the context of the asker's question, clearly the sizeof an int is 4 on his machine.

Comment: @Blackjack : Doesn't change the fact that many C programming errors are caused by the assertion that an int is 4 characters and that your answer continues the insidious spread of the myth. If you knew 4 is not correct, why did you write it?   I think we will have to agree to disagree, it's a bugbear of mine

Answer (score 4):

In C a character literal (constant) has type int.
So, consider the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("%zu\n", sizeof('a'));
  printf("%zu\n", sizeof('ab'));
  printf("%zu\n", sizeof('abc'));
  printf("%zu\n", sizeof('abcd'));

  printf("%u\n", 'a');
  printf("%u\n", 'ab');
  printf("%u\n", 'abc');
  printf("%u\n", 'abcd');

  printf("%x\n", 'a');
  printf("%x\n", 'ab');
  printf("%x\n", 'abc');
  printf("%x\n", 'abcd');

  printf("%c\n", 'a');
  printf("%c\n", 'ab');
  printf("%c\n", 'abc');
  printf("%c\n", 'abcd');
}
```

The first four statements all consider the literals as **one** character constant and they all print 4 == sizef(int), at least on gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3.
Note that this compiler prints several warnings for the above program:

```
warning: multi-character character constant
```

Basically, a character literal specifies the four bytes making up an int,
from left to right, higher-order byte first.
The missing leading bytes are filled with 0.
So, on my machine the second and third  group of printf statements print

```
97
24930
6382179
1633837924
61
6162
616263
61626364
```

In the hexadecimal output you see the layout of the four characters in the
literal (the ASCII codes from left to right): the 'a' is mapped to the
highest-order byte 0x61).

Finally, the fourth group prints:

```
a
b
c
d
```

i.e. the character literals are pushed on the stack as integers, but printf
only prints the lowest byte of that int as a char.

C++ behaves in a similar way, but one-byte character literals are considered
of type char, not int. The program

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  cout << sizeof('a') << endl;
  cout << sizeof('ab') << endl;
  cout << sizeof('abc') << endl;
  cout << sizeof('abcd') << endl;

  cout << 'a' << endl;
  cout << 'ab' << endl;
  cout << 'abc' << endl;
  cout << 'abcd' << endl;
}
```

will compile using GCC and give a similar warning. Its output is different
from that of C:

```
1
4
4
4
a
24930
6382179
1633837924
```

So one-byte character literals are treated as char, while multi-byte literals
are treated as int.

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

I ran my tests on a 32-bit Linux system on which an int has 4 bytes. It would be
interesting to see what happens on other systems, e.g. on a 64-bit system.

**EDIT**

Fixed answer (thanks for the hint): character literals have type int in C, they
are not cast to int.

Comment: Most systems have 4-byte `int`, except 16-bit ones.

Comment: Small incorrectness: character constants don't get cast to `int`, they _have_ type `int` in C.

Comment: Thanks, I will fix this. This means that they are cast to char each time they are assigned.

Comment: @larsmans: I have never seen an implementation with int taking up 64-bits, but as far as I know the initial idea was that in C int corresponds to the width of a processor register. Nevertheless, I think that with 64-bit processors it is more natural to have 8-bit char, 16-bit short, 32-bit int, 64-bit long (64-bit int would feel a bit awkward to me).

Comment: Also I was a bit surprised that 'abcd' is represented as 0x61626364 on a little-endian architecture, somehow I was expecting 0x64636261.

Comment: @Giorgio: the problem with 64-bit `int` is that you'd have a "gap" lower down in the integer type hierarchy and no way to implement `int32_t` in terms of the standard types.

Comment: @larsmans: Yes, that's what I had in mind. One would have a gap in the lower part of the integer hierarchy while the types int, long and long long would overlap (unless e.g. long is 128 bits and long long 256 bits).