# C: Explain sizeof behaviour

Tags: c, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Size of character ('a') in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172943/size-of-character-a-in-c-c)

Can someone explain why in C `sizeof(char)` = 1 and `sizeof(name[0])` = 1 but `sizeof('a')` = 4?

`name[0]` in this case would be `char name[1] = {'a'};`

I've tried to read through C's documentation to get this but I simply don't get it! if `sizeof('a')` and `sizeof(name[0])` were both 4 I would get it, if they were both 1 that would make sense... but I don't get the discrepancy!

Comment: I think `'a'` is `int` type rather than `char` type.

Comment: @PhilipKendall thanks for pointing that out, for some reason it didn't come up in my search!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C, character literals such as `'a'` have type `int`, and hence `sizeof('a')` is equal to `sizeof(int)`.

In C++, character literals have type `char`, and thus `sizeof('a')` is equal to `sizeof(char)`.

**References:**

**C99 Standard: 6.4.4.4 Character constants

Para 2:**

> An integer character constant is a sequence of one or more multibyte characters enclosed
>   in single-quotes, as in `’x’` or `’ab’`.

**C++03 Standard: 2.13.2 Character literals**
**Para 1:**

> A character literal is one or more characters enclosed in single quotes, as in `’x’`, optionally preceded by the letterL, as in `L’x’`. A character literal that does not begin with `L` is an ordinary character literal, also referred to as a narrow-character literal. **An ordinary character literal that contains a single c-char has type `char`**, with value equal to the numerical value of the encoding of the c-char in the execution character set.

Comment: In both C and C++ character constants are integers; it is the type that is important.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: I edited to make it more clear.

Comment: That now makes my answer redundant.

Answer (score 0):

In c, sizeof operator consider 'a' as integer so you are getting **4** as a size