# Why is this program's output different between C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Size of character ('a') in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172943/size-of-character-a-in-c-c)

The following program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", sizeof('\0'));
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(0));
}
```

compiled with gcc outputs

```
4
4
```

and with g++

```
1
4
```

Why is this happening? I know this it's not a compiler thing but a difference between C and C++ but what's the reason?

Comment: More like _language_-dependent!

Comment: Why were you doing this in the first place, out of curiosity?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In C, character constants **have type `int`** per 6.4.4.4(10) of the standard,

> An integer character constant has type int. The value of an integer character constant
>   containing a single character that maps to a single-byte execution character is the
>   numerical value of the representation of the mapped character interpreted as an integer.

Thus you're printing out the size of an `int` twice.

In C++, character constants have type `char`.

Answer (score 12):

The `\0` character literal is treated as an `int` in C, so you actually end up printing `sizeof(int)` instead of `sizeof(char)`.

`ideone` gives the same results ([C](http://ideone.com/e4G6k), [C++](http://ideone.com/F1CKS)).

Comment: @Konrad, true, everything smaller than an `int` is considered as an `int` in C. Fixed.

Comment: No, that’s also not true, not *everything* is treated as `int`, only character literals: http://ideone.com/ZQIPC

Comment: @Konrad, the `short` test in your example uses a cast. Of course, there is no way to express a `short` literal, so even a value fitting in a `short` is parsed as an `int` from the get-go. Indeed, it would be interesting to know if a would-be `short` literal would be treated the same way as a `char` one...

Comment: But your comment doesn’t talk about literals, it talks about *values*. And since C simply doesn’t have integer literals for anything other than `int`, the comment wouldn’t make sense if it talked about literals (rather than values) anyway.

Comment: @Konrad, ah, I was actually talking about literals (`int` and `char` ones, since `short` literals do not actually exist), not values. I agree my comment is ambiguous, though, I probably should have found a better way to express that.

Answer (score 4):

In C character literals are ints. In C++ they are chars.

Answer (score 0):

The output is already compiler dependent since you use the wrong format specifier for `size_t` this would be `%zu`. On 64 bit systems with `size_t` wider than `int` this could give you any sort of garbage.

Otherwise this shure is compiler dependent. Both values that you try to print the size of are `int` in C and `char` and `int` in C++. So in C this should usually give you `4 4` or `8 8` and in in C++ `1 4` or `1 8`.