# what is the result of printf("%d\n", sizeof('a')) in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Size of character ('a') in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172943/size-of-character-a-in-c-c)

OS: linuxmint 32-bit

Compiler: gcc & g++

I have try this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",sizeof('a'));
    return 0;
}
```

and I compile it with gcc , the result is `4`, and I change to g++, and it is `1`

then I use:
`sizeof(char)`, and the result is `1`

I use:
char s = 'a';
printf('%d\n', sizeof(s));

and the result is `1`

but I search in the Internet, and some people said that they get the result of `1` or `2`.

So why there are so many different result?

Comment: The type of character constants like 'a' in C is int. In C++, it is char.

Comment: Besides not having search the site for a similar question, you also should take care of `printf`. `%d` is never the right format for printing a value of type `size_t` since this is an unsigned type and in addition may have a width that differs from `int`.

Comment: @JensGustedt: The format for `size_t` is `"zu"` (assuming your implementation has caught up to the late 20th century).

Comment: @KeithThompson, `%zu` is only valid for C99. This is a question about the intersection of C and C++. Has C++ adopted this, too?

Comment: @JensGustedt: The ISO C11 standard includes the C99 library by reference, so yes, C++ has adopted `"%zu"`.  For pre-1999 C or pre-2011 C++, you can use `printf("%lu", (unsigned long)s)`, or `printf("%d", (int)s)` is ok if you know the value isn't too big.

Comment: @KeithThompson, you mean ISO C11++? Good to know that this will be fixed as soon as all compilers/libraries comply to C11++. So for the time being if you are programming for the intersection of C/C++ you'd have to use the `%lu` plus cast variant.

Comment: @JensGustedt: I meant ISO C++11 (not "C11++").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character constants are represented as `int` in C. When you are specifying `char` type, it's only 1 byte.

Answer (score 1):

Character literals like `'a'` have type `int` in C89 which is the default standard used by `gcc`. In C++ it is important for overloading that characters and strings have types `char` and `char*` respectively (think about `std::cout << 'a'`). Since `sizeof(int) == 4` and `sizeof(char) == 1` on x86 and x64_86 you get the results you describe.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(char)` is always 1, both in C and C++. In C, the type of `'c'` is `int`, so `sizeof('c')` is the same as `sizeof(int)`. In C++, the type of `'c'` is `char`, so `sizeof('c')` is the same as `sizeof(char)`, i.e., 1.