# how to write data within malloc memory in C

Tags: malloc, strcpy

Suppose I have

```
void * space= malloc(500) //alloc a block of memory
```

and I need to write two strings and an int: "Hello  world", "Goodbye friend",5 in memory address 50,150,380, correspondance to space.I tried the approach:

```
int * insert = (int *)(space +380);
*insert = 5;

char * insert2 = (char *)(space+50);
*insert2 = "Hello world";

char * insert3 = (char *)(space + 150);
strcpy(insert3,"Goodbye friend");
```

the int has no problem, but the two string throws error messages. so what's the correct method to do this? Also, how can you check if there is an overlap in memory between those inputs (the string inputed can be arbitarily long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172943/size-of-character-a-in-c-c#2172948), I'm pretty sure that you trying to store `"H"` (which is a constant in C) that is of type **int** into insert2. In other words, your trying to store a type `int` (`sizeof("H") == 2` on my compiler) into a char (`sizeof(char) == 1`). From there, it is up to your compiler to allow this behavior or throw an error. Plus `"Hello world"` is an immutable string that is located only in ROM, so you can't directly modified the string anyways.

To demonstrate, I ran:

```
printf("val:%d\n", "H");
printf("val:%d\n", "He");
printf("val:%d\n", "He");\\note 2nd instance the same
printf("val:%d\n", "Hel");
printf("val:%d\n", "Hell");
printf("val:%d\n", "Hello");
printf("val:%d\n", "Hello ");
printf("val:%d\n", "Hello W");
printf("val:%d\n", "Hello Wo");
printf("val:%d\n", "Hello Wor");
printf("val:%d\n", "Hello Worl");
printf("val:%d\n", "Hello World");
```

Yields:

```
val:4196404
val:4196406
val:4196406\\note 2nd instance the same
val:4196409
val:4196413
val:4196418
val:4196424
val:4196431
val:4196439
val:4196448
val:4196458
val:4196469
```

As @Rasmus was saying:

```
char * insert2 = (char *)(space+50);
strcpy(insert2 , "Hello world\0");// the '\0' if changing strings
```

Should resolve the issue.
BUT, I do not see much practical use for this, besides being vague/indecipherable, and not to mention wasteful of memory (unless you calculate it all out), so I recommend just using a `struct`:

```
struct blockOfMem{
    int num;
    char* str1;
    char* str2;
};
....
struct blockOfMem space;
space.num = 5;
strcpy(space.str1, "Hello world\0");// the '\0' if changing strings
strcpy(space.str2, "Goodbye friend\0");// the '\0' if changing strings
```

This makes you code much more readable and practical to use.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, using strcpy i could make your code compile.

```
void * space= malloc(500); //alloc a block of memory
int * insert = (int *)(space +380);
*insert = 5;

char * insert2 = (char *)(space+50);
strcpy(insert2 , "Hello world");

char * insert3 = (char *)(space + 150);
strcpy(insert3,"Goodbye friend");
```

I would use strlen to get the length of the string and then sizeof(char). To get how much to allocate:

```
malloc(sizeof(int)+sizeof(char)*(1+strlen(string1))); // 1+ since you need to count the \0.
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/