# Why is sizeof('3') == 4 using the GCC compiler?

Tags: c, gcc, char, sizeof

Why is the output for the following program 4?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", sizeof('3'));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because `'x'` literals are `int`s, not `char`s.

Comment: This might help: [Size of character ('a') in C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172943/size-of-character-a-in-c-c)

Comment: @Shanpriya: What prompted you to ask this question? What did you expect this program to output and why?

Comment: @AndreyT :I thought the declaration as sizeof('3') or sizeof('a') as the values are enclosed within single quotes I thought they mean character would result in output as 1 and not 4.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the type of a character constant is `int`, not `char` (and the size of `int` on your platform is four).

The C99 draft specification says:

> An integer character constant has type int.

This might seem weird, but remember that you can do this:

```
const uint32_t png_IHDR = 'IHDR';
```

In other words, a single character constant can consist of more than one actual character (four, above). This means the resulting *value* cannot have type `char`, since then it would immediately overflow and be pointless.

Note: the above isn't a very *nice* way of doing what it seems to be implying, that's another discussion. :)

Answer (score 5):

Character literal is `int`.

In C type of character constant Like '3' is `int`.

`sizeof(character_constant)==sizeof(int)==> In your case sizeof(int)==4`

Where As the in C++ it is `char`

This difference can lead to inconsistent behavior in some code that is compiled as both C and C++.

```
memset(&i, 'a', sizeof('a'));   // Questionable code
```

Comment: The value of a constant does not decide its type. `'3'` could have been the constant `51` of type `char`, but it isn't.

Comment: indeed modified accordingly. thanks.