# Why does this program give the following output?

Tags: c

When I ran this program it gave an output of

1, 4, 4

Why does sizeof('A') gives 4 bytes? Is 'A' treated as integer? If so, then why?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
char ch = 'A';
printf("%d, %d, %d", sizeof(ch), sizeof('A'), sizeof(3.14f));
return 0;
}
```

Moreover, when I replace

```
printf("%d, %d, %d", sizeof(ch), sizeof('A'), sizeof(3.14f));
```

with,

```
printf("%d, %d, %d", sizeof(ch), sizeof("A"), sizeof(3.14f));
```

It gives the output

1, 2, 4

which is even more confounding.

P.S.: I used compileonline.com to test this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, the type of `'A'` is `int`, which explains why `sizeof('A')` is `4` (since evidently your platform has 32-bit `int`). For more information, see [Size of character ('a') in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172943/size-of-character-a-in-c-c)

When compiled as C++, the first program prints `1 1 4`.

`"A"` is a string literal consisting of the letter A followed by the NUL character. Since it's two characters long, `sizeof("A")` is `2`.

Answer (score 1):

1.sizeof operator provide the size of input argument.
2.Size of a vaiable is machine(complier) dependent.In you case it is 32 bit.
3.`sizeof(ch)=1` because you declare as char.
4.`sizeof('A')=4` because compiler treats the literal constant as an integer.
5.`sizeof("A")=2` because its a string of 2 bye.In the case string,if u write a single character also compiler insert null character at the end.so its size is 2 bytes.
4.`sizeof(3.13f)=4` because its size of float is 4 bytes

Comment: which processor gives `33`bit?

Answer (score 0):

I generally suggest to use `sizeof` on *types* or on *variables*. Using `sizeof` on literal constants seems confusing (except perhaps on literal strings, to compute 1 + their string length at compile time).

The literal `'A'` is in *C* an `int` whose size is 4 on your machine.

The literal string `"A"` is exactly like

```
   const char literal_A_string[] = {'A', (char)0};
```

whose size is obviously 2 bytes (because each literal string has a terminal null byte appended).