# What is the difference between %c and %s in C

Tags: c

When to use %s instead of %c. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void) {

        char name[31] = "My name is Arnold";

        printf(" %c \n", name);

        return 0;


}
```

If I change %c to %s I get : My name is Arnold, but if change %s to %c I get something weird like this:

```
 ▒
```

Comment: It i not C, it is `printf` in C.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Passing wrong arguments to format specifiers is **undefined behavior**. Therefore you obtain such a weird output.

1. `"%s"` expects a pointer to a null-terminated string (`char*`).
2. `"%c"` expects a character (`int`). Surprised? Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172943/size-of-character-a-in-c-c).

To print the n<sup>th</sup> character of `name`, use

```
printf(" %c \n", name[n]);
```

Comment: Strictly spealing, `"%c"` expectes `int`.  `char` will automatically be extended to `int` for arguments. Quote from [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 7.19.6.1 The fprintf function : "c If no l length modifier is present, the int argument is converted to an
unsigned char, and the resulting character is written."

Comment: @MikeCAT Argh, yes, forgot about that that's different from C++. Thanks.