# Why "$" is printed when I try to run the C code below?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
printf("%c\n","\"\"\"\"\"");

}
```

This prints $ but not """""

Why "$" is printed when I try to run the C code above?

Comment: `"%c"` is for a *single* `char`. Mismatching format specifier and argument leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). UB (Undefined Behavior) means there's no use in discussing behavior.

Comment: [What is the difference between %c and %s in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33856654/what-is-the-difference-between-c-and-s-in-c/33856673)

Answer (score 1):

You pass a string to `printf`, not a char. Try `'"'`

What happens in your code is that the string is passed to `printf`, but `printf` expects a char. `printf` now tries to interpret the address of this string as a char. In general, this is *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0):

`%c` is the format specifier for a single character; there is probably some conversion going on. You want `%s` (for strings).

Answer (score 0):

It actually prints some garbage, because your input is not a single character, is a sequence of characters. Try using %s instead of %c