# why char a = '48'; couts only 8?

Tags: c++

Iam beginner in c++ , so why this happens

for Example :

```
            char b = 48; // cout's 0

            char b = '48'; // cout's only 8
```

Comment: Because you can't have a char with multiple chars in it...

Comment: As to why the first b cout's 0, it's related to the position of numerical symbols (aka digits) in the (E)ASCII table: https://www.qwant.com/?q=ascii+table&client=ext-firefox-light-sb. 48 just so happen to be where '0' is held, so cout'ing a character which value is '48' will result in the string '0' being output.

Comment: @Mad Physicist  do you mean '4' and '8' are 2 separate chars?

Comment: Because [Why should I always enable conpiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warning)

Answer (score 3):

```
char b = 48; // cout's 0
```

This output `0` because the character `0` has [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) value of `48`.

```
char b = '48'; // cout's only 8
```

This output `8` because you can only have one character in `char` type varibale.

Comment: Be careful how you word that. Technically multi-character literals are completely valid in C++. They have a type of `int` but their actual value is implementation defined. I would guess in this instance the '8' is the low byte of the integer and assigning to a `char` has simply truncated the value.

Comment: if you're on a big endian machine the it'll likely print out `4` instead of 8

Answer (score 0):

When you assign an `integer` to a `character` type variable, the variable stores the character defined by the `integer`(assuming it's an ASCII code).

But when you are assigning `character` type data in a `character` type variable, it stores the last assigned `character` to the variable.

Comment: in C `'8'` is an int, but this question is tagged [tag:c++] and in C++ it's a `char`

Comment: I didn't understand completely. Can you please provide some reference related to this ?

Comment: there are a lot of questions on SO: [Size of character ('a') in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2172943/995714), [Why are C character literals ints instead of chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/433895/995714)... *"But when you are assigning character type data in a character type variable, it stores the last assigned character to the variable"* is also **wrong**, since the value of multi-character literal is implementation-defined [C++ multicharacter literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3960954/995714)

Comment: "stores the character defined by the integer" -- don't get hung up on "character". A value is a value, and a `char` variable holds an integral value. On output the **value** in a `char` variable is used to decide which character to **display** (and that's where ASCII or some other encoding comes in). On input each character typed on the keyboard is interpreted as an integral value (again depending on the encoding in use, which is almost always ASCII these days).

Comment: @phuclv -- in `char b = '8';` it doesn't matter whether the type of `'8'` is `int` or `char`. It works exactly as expected. It's the `'48'` that's funky.