# Size of a character is showing 2 bytes in ANSI C?

Tags: c

I want to know the reason behind why I am getting 2 bytes as a size of the character and at the same time 1 byte for the similar character when stored in a place-holder.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    void main(void) {
    char a = "$";
    printf("%d\n", sizeof("$")); // Here output is 2 which should be 1
    printf("%d", sizeof(a)); // Here output is 1 which is correct
    }
```

Comment: '$' is char whereas "$" is a null terminated string.

Comment: `char a = "$";` is wrong, and your compiler should warn you about that. It’s `char a = '$';`. Your compiler should also warn you about `%d`; it should be `%zu` for a size.

Comment: `'$'` has type `int`, ie `sizeof '$' == sizeof (int)`... `"$"` has type `/*read-only*/char[2]`.

Comment: Can I know the reason why the 'char' type variable is regarded as an 'int' type by the compiler?

Comment: @Ricky_Rick https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172943/size-of-character-a-in-c-c

Answer (score 0):

it treats "$" as a string, so it's NULL terminated and has a sizeof 2.
same would happen if you would do sizeof "a".
if you want to get the sizeof the character itself you should do sizeof with '$', that's the symbol for character.

Comment: `sizeof '$' == sizeof (int)` because type of `'$'` is `int` (not `char`)

Comment: you're correct, I accidently tested it on C++ not C.