# sizeof characters C/C++

Tags: c++, c

**in C**

```
printf ("%d",sizeof ('a'));
```

output: 4

**in C++**

```
printf ("%d",sizeof ('a'));
```

output: 1
**Why the outputs do not equal?**

Comment: In C, the type of a character constant is `int`, while in C++ it's `char`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Size of character ('a') in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172943/size-of-character-a-in-c-c) This is only one of the many possible dupes found with [this search](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=sizeof+character+constant+different+in+c+and+c%2B%2B+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Comment: *Why the outputs do not equal?* -- Because the first one is `C` and the second one is `C++`.  Now you know one reason why C and C++ are two different languages.

Comment: Side note: `%d` is not the correct specifier, `%zu` is.

Comment: Addendum: If you check the documentation for them, you'll find most of the <ctype.h> helper functions don't take `char`s. They take `int`s.

Answer (score 1):

In C, the 'a' is considered `int` with a size of `sizeof(int)`. While in C++, the 'a' is considered a `char` with a size of 1.

Comment: @FadyHany No, in that case, `c` is a `char` with a size of 1.

Answer (score 1):

In C type of a char constant is a int while in C++ its a char