# Unaligned memory access in -O3 only

Tags: c, gcc, arm, memory-alignment

I'm using GCC as compiler and my target is a Cortex-R52 (armv8-r) core.

Being `char *str`, I have the following piece of code

```
*++str = '0';
```

When I compile it using `-O2` or `-Os` , gcc is generating the following assembly code:

```
movs    r3,#0x30
strb    r0,[r1,#0x2]
strb    r3,[r1,#0x1]
```

which executes well. However, if I use `-O3` instead, gcc generates the following:

```
movs    r3,#0x30
strh    r3,[r1,#0x1]
```

which causes a data abort exception, with `DFSR = 0x0000_0A21` (Data Fault Status), which translates to `Alignment Fault`, `Abort caused by a write instruction` and `DFAR is valid`. In both cases, `r1 = 0x2000_0910`, and in the second scenario I can see `DFAR = 0x2000_0911`.

As far as I can tell, the difference between `strb` and `strh` is that the first stores a byte (8 bits) and the second stores a halfword (16 bits). I've tried modifying `r1` so it holds `0x2000_0911` in the second scenario, and the issue does not happen. I am guessing that having a half word access in a memory address that is not 2-byte aligned gives you an error.

Would this be correct? If so, why is gcc creating this assembly and what options I have to fix it?

Note: I'm using other flags as well, but since they are all the same for both scenarios I don't know whether it's relevant.

**Edit #1**

- The issue is gone after adding `-mno-unaligned-access` flag (thanks to @Eugene Sh. for the tip). Now `-O3` flag generates the same x2 `strb` instructions as the `-O2` flag. The question I would have now is: was the problem not including this flag, or is there something else wrong?
- Size of `'0'` is 4 bytes (and size of `char` is 1 byte). [stackoverflow.com/questions/2172943/size-of-character-a-in-c-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172943/size-of-character-a-in-c-c). Not sure what this means though, since as mentioned in the comments the compiler  is generating a 2-byte access.
- The exact compiler I'm using is `NXP GCC for Arm Embedded Processors v10.2 build 1728; Version: 1728; Build id: 202307190908`. So not a standard gcc compiler
- I would need some time to create a standalone version of the issue, and I'm not sure whether it's worth it as my issue is now gone. In case it helps, the full list of compiler flags I'm using is: -mcpu=cortex-r52
  -mthumb
  -mlittle-endian
  -mfloat-abi=hard
  -mfpu=neon-fp-armv8
  -mtp=soft
  -ffreestanding
  -fno-common
  -fdata-sections
  -ffunction-sections
  -fno-builtin
  -Wl,--build-id=none
  -std=c17
  -O3

Comment: There's not enough here to see what the problem might be.  Please update your post to include a [mcve] that others can compile *as is* and run and see the same error you do.

Comment: What is `str` pointing at?

Comment: Higher optimization levels don't always make a program run faster or be smaller or use less memory, and sometimes they make a program produce different results. But if your code has well-defined behavior according to the C language spec, and changing only the optimization level causes it to crash, then that probably indicates a flaw in your compiler.

Comment: Use the `-mno-unaligned-access` flag to the compiler to instruct it not to generate unaligned access. Since the unaligned access can be permitted or restricted on different ARM processors in the runtime (as on ARMv7a, not sure about armv8-r), the compiler needs to know if it is allowed to do this.

Comment: have you correctly defined the processor using command line options? If yes - report the issue on buzilla

Comment: The C code you show us only writes to one byte (a char is 1 byte on your system, right?) but both assembly snippets are writing to two bytes.  GCC isn't normally *that* buggy, so I strongly suspect you are leaving out important details.  Please provide a [mcve].  A link to a https://godbolt.org showing your results would be very useful.

Comment: @0___________ [buzilla](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gviLt0v25Oc)? Looks like a buggy comment.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I've tested it and `'0'` is actually 4 bytes, while `char` is 1 byte, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172943/size-of-character-a-in-c-c. Not sure what that means though, since as you mention in both cases compiler generates a 2-byte access...